# How to copy the text that shows up when using Google/Firebug chrome element inspector?

Tags: google-chrome

[image]Using web developer tools and looking to copy css as I hover, attaching an image to make it easier to understand.

[image]

Comment: Questions about the [usage of web browsers](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is considered off-topic here. You could ask this over at [Super User](http://superuser.com/) but be sure to search for similar questions there first. The hover text you want to copy is the CSS that's rendered by the browser, and can be found by right clicking to inspect the element and then viewing it under the _Styles_ tab.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the inspect element -> right click on code then you found option of copy selector :)[image: image here]

In right side style there is a + button click to get css selector of the element.

Comment: Doesn't work, the pop up disapears as soon as you move the mouse, using ctrl c doesn't work either

Comment: Did you tried disabled JavaScript??

Comment: Yes not working

Comment: Hey!! What do you mean that pop up disappeared

Comment: Right click on code in in inspect element

Comment: The _Copy selector_ option doesn't necessarily return the same text as seen in the popup tooltip (although it is sometimes _similar_). For example, take the image in the question: The popup tooltip simply shows "`img 508px x 206px`", however, _Copy selector_ returns "`#question > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.postcell > div > div.post-text > p:nth-child(2) > a > img`".

Comment: As w3dk says, it doesn't always work, inconsistent....I'm not sure there is a solution for this? Firebug has similar problem

Comment: Solution is to get Firefox 24.6.0  , this version lets you copy the css in the pop up, when clicking on select, it stays there,and you can move your mouse to it, select it and copy it with ctrl+C, there is no right mouse copy but it works. It's  available on Source Forge under portable apps edition, if someone knows a newer version or solution to this please post.

Comment: i'm doing this with my crome and firefox, i am wondering why this not works for you